# Print angle rotate gesture

Tags: swiftui, rotation, gesture

I want print value angle rotate, but
Text (self.finaldegree)
don’t working.

Code:

```
@State var degree: Angle = Angle(degrees: 0)
@State var finaldegree: Angle = Angle(degrees: 0)
       var body: some View {
            VStack { 
            Image("Encoder_White1")
                .padding(100)
                .scaleEffect(2)
                .rotationEffect(degree+finaldegree)
                    .gesture(RotationGesture()
                        .onChanged{ value in
                            degree = value
                           }
                       .onEnded{ value in
                           finaldegree = value
                           degree = Angle(degrees: 0)
                          })     
            
        }
    }
```

Text (self.finaldegree)

Comment: use `Text(finaldegree.degrees.formatted())` and put it inside the `VStack`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you're trying to do, as there's a a lot of extra code that's probably not needed.

```
Text(self.finaldegree)
```

won't work by itself, as `Text` expects a `String`, or a value that can formatted as a `String` (e.g. `Int`, `Double`, `Date`). If you convert your angle into a double (e.g using `.degrees`), you can then format that for display, e.g.

```
Text(angle.degrees, format: .number)
```

A simplified solution to your code might be:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var angle: Angle = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "questionmark")
                .padding(100)
                .scaleEffect(4)
                .rotationEffect(angle)
                .gesture(
                    RotationGesture()
                        .onChanged{ value in
                            angle = value
                        }
                    )
            Text("\(Text(angle.degrees, format: .number))°")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]